# Exporting HTML To Excel in IE11 – "Access is Denied"

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer-11, access-denied

I am needing to export an HTML report to excel in various different browsers (preferably solely on the client). I have put numerous hours into this problem, and I have working, browser-specific solutions for IE10+ and FF/Chrome. What I am seeking is a cross-browser solution as I cringe at browser-specific code.

```
var saveData = (function () {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function (data, fileName) {
    var html = data,
    blob = new Blob([html], { type: "text/xml" }),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
}());

var fileName = "download.xls"
saveData($('#TablesContainer').html(), fileName);
```

http://codepen.io/mhodges44/pen/dGWZvN

This solution is working in FF/Chrome and mostly works in IE, but I get the following error on the a.click() execution: “SCRIPT5: Access is denied.” I have programmatically triggered click events in IE11 before, so I am not sure why it is denying the execution. Does it have to do with XSS security with a file download or what?

Please do not respond with a “window.open(‘data:application….’)” solution or a navigator.msSaveBlob() solution because they are not cross-browser compatible.

Worst case, I just leave the browser-specific code, but hopefully there’s a solution I have not seen or thought of.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why not just use FileSaver.js? Or are you rolling your own solution for the experience

Comment: I have looked at FileSaver.js. To be completely honest, our project is pretty massive as-is, so I try to avoid adding library after library. Especially since this problem is a pretty small use-case in our application. If there's an easy solution without using a third-party library, it would be preferred. Otherwise I'm definitely open to it.

Comment: IE has pretty heavy security, triggering a click on a hidden anchor is a no no, but that is a non issue since IE does not support the download attribute on the anchor tag.

Comment: As is suggested by good OOP practice anyways, I would encapsulate the functionality from the FileSaver.js library that you intend to use.. Unless by project size, you mean 'total file size' in which case pouring through their code for the cross-browser applicability (and copying the revelant parts) might be a good idea

Comment: Understood. Thanks guys. What I mean by project size is just the application as a whole - the sheer number of files involved. Adding another small use-case library is not the end of the world, but it's something I like to avoid if I can. I'll parse through the files and see if I can't figure out what they're doing and extract out what I need.

Comment: I ended up using filesaver.js. I extracted out the parts of the code that I needed and the code itself to export the file was 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if window.navigator and window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob
      blob = new Blob([ data ], type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob blob
else 
      blob = new Blob([ data ], type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
      objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      window.open objectUrl
```

Comment: I ended up using filesaver.js. I extracted out the parts of the code that I needed and the code itself to export the file was 1 line. I wanted a solution that did not require me to manually detect a browser and run different code. Thanks though